# Telegram bot is stack on inifinity loop

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I made a bot that needs to run in an infinity loop until the user will tell him to stop. I created an easy concept for my program that follows the same tasks. The bot doesn't respond to other messages while I wrote "/start". Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?
Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

My bot is taking the input message from users and using it as a search keyword for websites with listings(that part of the code works perfectly). But I need that loop to constantly reload the page and check listings.  **But I want the user to be able to disable the loop by command**

````py
import telebot
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
s=Service("C:\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)

link_tmp = ""
loope = False
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
bot = AsyncTeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

async def start(message):
    print("work")
    loope = True
    loop_time = 0
    while loope is True:
        link = "https://www.vinted.co.uk/vetements?brand_id[]=326054&order=newest_first&search_text="
        print(link)
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(2)
        if loop_time == 0:
            policy_but = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = """//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]""")
            time.sleep(1)
            policy_but.click()
            time.sleep(1)
        first_item = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div/section/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[13]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/a")
        urll= first_item.get_attribute("href")
        first_item.click()
        first_item_pic = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/main/div/section/div[1]/figure[1]/a")
        picturee = first_item_pic.get_attribute("href")
        if loop_time == 0:
            link_tmp = urll
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"""New: {urll}

            Photo: {picturee}""")
        else:
            if urll != link_tmp:
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"""New: {urll}

            Photo: {picturee}""")
            link_tmp = urll
        loop_time = loop_time + 1

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
async def stop(message):
    loope = False
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "stop")

import asyncio

asyncio.run(bot.polling(non_stop=True)) ```
````

Comment: `loope` is never set to `False` in the `start` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use loop in your function because it prevents replying to another messages.

just check this example:
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/asynchronous_telebot/echo_bot.py

Comment: But I need a loop.  My scripts basically read the listing of the selling websites and alert the user when something new got uploaded. That part of the code is working fine but. This loop of constantly refreshing and checking websites need to be there

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please provide the code that solves the OP's problem. If the link doesn't work in the future, this answer will not be helpful without code.

Comment: use `global loope` @kaban69

Comment: don't use infinite loop